# Why does while loop create an error in my code?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to execute the following code. The code below works well when I replace while(n>9) by if (n>9). Can someone explain me why does while loop cause this error??

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, digit, i, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      { 
        digit = n % 10;
          while (n > 9)
           {
            n = (n - digit) / 10;
           }
        sum = sum + digit;
     }
    printf("%d", sum); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also include the error message you're getting (or otherwise what error you're talking about - I don't even know whether you're referring to a compilation error or some other kind of error).

Comment: @feixiang done that.

Comment: @sepp2k This code is suppose to give sum of all the digits of a 5digit number. While loop produces a wrong output.

Comment: Replace the 4 lines of nonsense which follow `digit = n % 10;` with the line `n /= 10;`

Comment: @ShreyaRajput So your question is why using a `while` loop doesn't produce the exact same behavior as using an `if` statement? If so, the answer is: because while loops loop and if statements don't.

Comment: @sepp2k I got it. Thank you.

Comment: OT: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used:  Suggest removing: `#include <string.h>` and `#include <math.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`  this limits the input value to a max of 99999.  Much better to use: `for (i = 0; n; i++)` and since the variable 'i' is no longer being used, suggest replacing the `if()` statement with: `while( n )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. after applying the proposed corrections to the code,
2. and applying the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most)
   one variable declaration per statement.*
3. the following proposed code
   performs the desired functionality
    results:   cleanly compiles
   properly checks for and handles errors
   the call to `printf()` format string ends with '\n' so the data is immediately output to the terminal
   displays an appropriate way to extract the digits from a 'int' and gather the sum of those digits

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int n;
    int digit;
    int  sum = 0;

    if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for initial value failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    while( n )
    { 
        digit = n % 10;  // extract a digit
        n /= 10;         // reduce the working number
        sum = sum + digit;
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);   // use '\n' so value immediately output to terminal
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: the inner `while()` loop can be further reduced to: `whie( n ) { sum += n % 10;  n /= 10; }`

Comment: Is this only code makeup or meant to be a solution and answe? If the latter please add an explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch,  This is a very clear answer/solution.  However, since the comments to the question covered the faults in the OPs code, I have not repeated them in my answer.